# How to get text contained between brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have 3 different string values in my console application:

Student A (AA.1)

Student(1) B (AA.2)

Student B

Would like to get value from backet:

AA.1, AA.2

Thanks. I have used split, however will encounter error because of **Student B** does not have any bracket and **Student(1) B (AA.2)** have 2 brackets.

**Current Code**

```
 char[] targetExpression = new char[] { '(', ')' };
 string title = "Student A (AA.1)";
 Console.WriteLine(title.Split(targetExpression)[1]);
```

Comment: split on whitespace and check if the first char is a '('

Answer (score 1):

looking for something like this?

```
/.*\(([^)]*)\)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

**A function to get a string within characters**

```
string GetStirngWithiin(string SourceString, char startChar, char endChar,int StartFrom=0)
{
    SourceString = SourceString.Substring(StartFrom);
    int startFrom=SourceString.IndexOf(startChar);
    int EndAt=SourceString.IndexOf(endChar);
    if ((startFrom > -1) && (EndAt >-1))
    {
       int SubStrLength = EndAt - startFrom - 1;
        if (SubStrLength > 0)
        {
          string Result = SourceString.Substring(startFrom + 1, SubStrLength);
          return Result;
         }

      }
   return "";
}
```

> you can use the function calls as

```
 string str1 = GetStirngWithiin("Student A (AA.1)",'(',')');
 string str2 = GetStirngWithiin("Student(1) B (AA.2))", '(', ')',10);
```

using with Student B will return a blank string.